# Best practice for exposing record IDs to API users

Tags: mysql

I am extending an API to include the ability to retrieve and update a specific record after the record is created by the user.

Currently, these records are created with an auto generated integer key, for example `49300`.

Users need a way to access a specific record but I don't like the idea of exposing this ID to end users, because it will reveal information about my schema, for example I can assume there is also a record of ID `493299`.

I've considered a GUID alongside the auto generated integer, but I have concerns about performance as the table size

Comment: So what if they know there's a record with ID 493299? They shouldn't be able to do anything with it if they don't have permission to access it.

Comment: _Users need a way to access a specific record_ Is that your requirement? Or is it your users' requirement?

Comment: @Abra That's the ability he's adding as stated in the first line.

Comment: @Barmar This can leak information to competitors like how many users you have, etc.

Comment: Create an additional column with some kind of "public ID" that could be a GUID or UUID or otherwise, whatever you want.

Comment: @tadman That might be something you want to advertise -- We have over 100,000 users.

Comment: @Barmar Or you have a lot of rewound transactions that burn up IDs!

Comment: The internal keys need never be exposed to the end user. One way of achieving this is to have an internal AI, and an 'external' random (and unique) string. Another way (not easily available in MySQL) is whole dataset encryption.